# Good Sources for Lecture Movies in Set Theory, Logic and Philosophy of Maths

Tags: reference-request, logic, set-theory, big-list, philosophy

Of course as any other researcher I'm not able to attend any scientific event in my research area. But it is always interesting and useful to watch the lecture movies of these events.

> I will appreciate if you help me by introducing some links and sources to some lecture movies (or any other type of movies including debates, documentaries, etc.) particularly related to set theory, Logic and philosophy of maths.

Answer (score 5):

[Gresham College](http://www.gresham.ac.uk) website is a general source for Public Scientific Lectures including different branches of logic.

See also these video lectures from [Institute for Advanced Study](https://video.ias.edu/):

- [Voevodsky - What if Current Foundations of Mathematics are Inconsistent?](https://video.ias.edu/voevodsky-80th)
- [Voevodsky - Univalent Foundations: New Foundations of Mathematics](http://video.ias.edu/voevodsky14)
- [Magidor - Can the Continuum Problem be Solved?](http://video.ias.edu/csdm/magidor)
- [Kojman - Does Infinite Cardinal Arithmetic Resemble Number Theory?](https://video.ias.edu/members/kojman)
- [Bombieri - The Mathematical Infinity](https://video.ias.edu/The-Mathematical-Infinity)

And [these](http://www.worldsciencefestival.com/participants/w_hugh_woodin/) with Hugh Woodin and Keith Devlin participation in "Infinity Program".

[Here](https://www.birs.ca/events/2013/5-day-workshops/13w5026/videos) is a lecture by Justin Moore on Forcing.

The following sets of set theory video tapes are from Fields Institute video archive.

- [Three lectures of Foreman on large cardinals](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive/event/22/2012).
- [Workshop on Iterated Forcing and Large Cardinals](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive/event/45/2012).
- [Workshop on Forcing Axioms and their Applications](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive/event/101/2012).

Note: In above links click on the "static" button beside each title to watch the tape.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something to start with.

[Logic at Harvard - Exploring the Frontiers of Incompleteness](http://logic.harvard.edu/efi.php#multimedia).

Answer (score 2):

Another good alternative are the video lectures from [this web page](http://videolectures.net/Top/Computer_Science/Logic/).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [*Mathematics Illuminated*](http://www.learner.org/resources/series210.html) series ([Magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme) link: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:e7d9f0ab4e6bf8e9b7cadf37d0e6ba3285172352 ). Individual segments of that series can also be found on YouTube.